# How to make a fixed div/nav resize with the div it's inside of?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fixed

I'm pretty fresh to web development and cannot figure this one out. Appreciate any help!

On re-size the fixed div moves out of the container instead of re-sizing. The site I'm working on has the nav as the fixed section and is inside of the main container.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
<div class="container">
<div class="fixed"></div>
</div>

.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1600px;
}

.fixed {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KqvQr/

Comment: The problem is that the max-width property overrides the width property, but min-width will always override max-width whether followed before or after width in your declaration

Answer (score 0):

When you specify position as **fixed** the Element, even thought it is inside a parent container, It won't behave as a child of a parent container. It won't adjust his width according to the parent width. But I can give you a solution where when user resize the page the fixed **element also get resize yet it is a position fixed**

```
.fixed {
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid green;
   position: fixed;
   right:0;
   left:0;
}
```

Don't specify widths for the container. instead of that specify **left** and **right** values. so then when page is resizing css only check for the left and right margin values. by keeping those values it will adjust its inner width always.

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KqvQr/5/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve what you want if you stick with that constraints. Your `width` and `max-width` will work as expected if you change your position to `relative` instead of `fixed`..

Check out this Fiddle